# Searching if letters in a word are found in another word PHP Strings

Tags: php

Just like the title of this post says, I would to be able to check if every letter of a word is found in another word. So far these are the lines of codes that I was able to come up with:

```
<?php   
        $DBword = $_POST['DBword'];
        $inputWords = $_POST['inputWords'];

        $inputCount = str_word_count($inputWords,1);



        echo "<b>THE WORD:</b>"."<br/>".$DBword."<br/><br/>";
        echo "<b>WORDS ENTERED:</b><br/>";

            foreach($inputCount as $outputWords)
            {
                echo $outputWords."<br/>";
            }

            foreach($inputCount as $countWords)
            {
                for($i=0; $i<strlen($countWords); $i++)
                {$count = strpos( "$DBword", $countWords[$i]);}

                if($count === false)
                {
                    $score++;
                }


            }

            echo "<b><br/>TOTAL SCORE: </b>";
            echo $score;


        ?>
```

My point in having the `foreach` with the `$outputWords` is to just output the letters entered.
As for the other `foreach` that has `$countWords`, I am using it to really check if all letters in the word entered are found in the `$DBword`. I am using the `for` loop to check every letter.

So far, I am not getting the output that I want and I just ran out of ideas. Any ideas please?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want to do, but perhaps `echo substr_count($_POST['inputWords'], $_POST['DBword']);` would do the trick?

Comment: can you please review the answers you have been given and either accept the one that helped you most/solved your problem or point out why none of the answers solved your problem. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
function contains_letters($word1, $word2) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word1); $i++)
    if (strpos($word2, $word1{$i}) === false)
      return false;
  return true;
}

//example usage
if (contains_letters($_POST['inputWords'], $_POST['DBword']))
  echo "All the letters were found.";
```

If this check should be case-insensitive (i.e. 'A' counts as a usage of 'a'), change `strpos` to `stripos`.

Comment: Dan Grossman,
is this line:

`if (strpos($word2, $word1{$i}) === false)`

supposed to be like:

`if (strpos($word2, $word1[$i]) === false)`?

Comment: No, that was intentional. `{#}` is valid syntax for accessing the character at position `#` in a string. Array syntax also works, but didn't always in the past, as strings aren't arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are overwriting `$count` in the `for` loop for each letter in `$countWords`, `$count` will contain the position of the last letter of `$countWord` only. Also, I am not sure why you increase score when the letter *wasn't* found.

In any case, you are making your life more difficult than necessary.
PHP has a [function for counting chars in a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php):

```
return count_chars($dbWord, 3) === count_chars($inputWord, 3);
```

will return true if the same letters are found in both strings.

Example to find all the words having exactly the same letters:

```
$dbWord = count_chars('foobar', 3);
$inputWords = 'barf boo oof raboof boarfo xyz';
print_r(
    array_filter(
        str_word_count($inputWords, 1),
        function($inputWord) use ($dbWord) {
            return count_chars($inputWord, 3) === $dbWord;
        }
    )
);
```

will output "raboof" and "boarfo" only.